# Update a data frame with a second data frame

Tags: r

I have a null data frame which represents a time span for a selection of cities and three test results:

```
cities <- c('Boston', 'Chicago', 'Denver', 'HOuston', 'LosAngeles', 'Miami', 'NewYork', 'WashingtonDC')
years <- 2014:2018
df <- expand.grid(Year=years, City=cities, TestA=0, TestB=0, TestC=0)
df[with(df, order(Year, City)),]
head(df,12)

#    Year    City TestA TestB TestC
#1  2014  Boston     0     0     0
#2  2015  Boston     0     0     0
#3  2016  Boston     0     0     0
#4  2017  Boston     0     0     0
#5  2018  Boston     0     0     0
#6  2014 Chicago     0     0     0
#7  2015 Chicago     0     0     0
#8  2016 Chicago     0     0     0
#9  2017 Chicago     0     0     0
#10 2018 Chicago     0     0     0
#11 2014  Denver     0     0     0
#12 2015  Denver     0     0     0
```

I want to update it using a second data frame that looks like the following:

```
dfUpdate <- data.frame(Year=c(2016, 2015), City=c('Boston', 'Chicago'), 
TestA=c(12.23, 16.01), TestB=c('Joe', 'Sally'), TestC=c(1000, 1500) )
dfUpdate

#  Year    City TestA TestB TestC
#1 2016  Boston 12.23   Joe  1000
#2 2015 Chicago 16.01 Sally  1500
```

After the update the original data frame should look like:

```
#    Year    City TestA TestB TestC
# 1  2014  Boston     0     0     0
# 2  2015  Boston     0     0     0
# 3  2016  Boston 12.23   Joe  1000
# 4  2017  Boston     0     0     0
# 5  2018  Boston     0     0     0
# 6  2014 Chicago     0     0     0
# 7  2015 Chicago 16.01 Sally  1500
# 8  2016 Chicago     0     0     0
# 9  2017 Chicago     0     0     0
# 10 2018 Chicago     0     0     0
# ...
```

The updates will always have year and city values that are in 'df'.
The actual application will have over ten thousand observations for 'df' as there will be many years and cities.
The update data frame 'dfUpdate' may have several hundred observations.

I see some other solutions on Stack Overflow but they differ in that the data frame has a single index.

Comment: Why don’t you make a single index in both datasets and join from there? E.g., `year_city`

Comment: @Andrew - Joining on 2 index columns is perfectly acceptable too. OP should do a search here for "[r] update join"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to use `stringsAsFactors = F` when reading data frames to avoid conversion of strings to factors. Then use `for` loop in base `R`

```
for(i in 1:nrow(dfUpdate)) {
  df[df$Year == dfUpdate$Year[i] & df$City == dfUpdate$City[i], -c(1:2)] = dfUpdate[i, -c(1:2)]
}

> df
Year         City TestA TestB TestC
1  2014       Boston  0.00     0     0
2  2015       Boston  0.00     0     0
3  2016       Boston 12.23   Joe  1000
4  2017       Boston  0.00     0     0
5  2018       Boston  0.00     0     0
6  2014      Chicago  0.00     0     0
7  2015      Chicago 16.01 Sally  1500
8  2016      Chicago  0.00     0     0
9  2017      Chicago  0.00     0     0
10 2018      Chicago  0.00     0     0
11 2014       Denver  0.00     0     0
12 2015       Denver  0.00     0     0
13 2016       Denver  0.00     0     0
14 2017       Denver  0.00     0     0
15 2018       Denver  0.00     0     0
16 2014      HOuston  0.00     0     0
17 2015      HOuston  0.00     0     0
18 2016      HOuston  0.00     0     0
19 2017      HOuston  0.00     0     0
20 2018      HOuston  0.00     0     0
21 2014   LosAngeles  0.00     0     0
22 2015   LosAngeles  0.00     0     0
23 2016   LosAngeles  0.00     0     0
24 2017   LosAngeles  0.00     0     0
25 2018   LosAngeles  0.00     0     0
26 2014        Miami  0.00     0     0
27 2015        Miami  0.00     0     0
28 2016        Miami  0.00     0     0
29 2017        Miami  0.00     0     0
30 2018        Miami  0.00     0     0
31 2014      NewYork  0.00     0     0
32 2015      NewYork  0.00     0     0
33 2016      NewYork  0.00     0     0
34 2017      NewYork  0.00     0     0
35 2018      NewYork  0.00     0     0
36 2014 WashingtonDC  0.00     0     0
37 2015 WashingtonDC  0.00     0     0
38 2016 WashingtonDC  0.00     0     0
39 2017 WashingtonDC  0.00     0     0
40 2018 WashingtonDC  0.00     0     0
```

Comment: Nice and simple.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
    gather(k, v, -Year, -City) %>%
    distinct(Year, City, k) %>%
    left_join(dfUpdate %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>% gather(k, v, -Year, -City)) %>%
    spread(k, v, fill = 0) %>%
    arrange(City, Year)
#   Year         City TestA TestB TestC
#1  2014       Boston     0     0     0
#2  2015       Boston     0     0     0
#3  2016       Boston 12.23   Joe  1000
#4  2017       Boston     0     0     0
#5  2018       Boston     0     0     0
#6  2014      Chicago     0     0     0
#7  2015      Chicago 16.01 Sally  1500
#8  2016      Chicago     0     0     0
#9  2017      Chicago     0     0     0
#10 2018      Chicago     0     0     0
#11 2014       Denver     0     0     0
#12 2015       Denver     0     0     0
#13 2016       Denver     0     0     0
#14 2017       Denver     0     0     0
#15 2018       Denver     0     0     0
#16 2014      HOuston     0     0     0
#17 2015      HOuston     0     0     0
#18 2016      HOuston     0     0     0
#19 2017      HOuston     0     0     0
#20 2018      HOuston     0     0     0
#21 2014   LosAngeles     0     0     0
#22 2015   LosAngeles     0     0     0
#23 2016   LosAngeles     0     0     0
#24 2017   LosAngeles     0     0     0
#25 2018   LosAngeles     0     0     0
#26 2014        Miami     0     0     0
#27 2015        Miami     0     0     0
#28 2016        Miami     0     0     0
#29 2017        Miami     0     0     0
#30 2018        Miami     0     0     0
#31 2014      NewYork     0     0     0
#32 2015      NewYork     0     0     0
#33 2016      NewYork     0     0     0
#34 2017      NewYork     0     0     0
#35 2018      NewYork     0     0     0
#36 2014 WashingtonDC     0     0     0
#37 2015 WashingtonDC     0     0     0
#38 2016 WashingtonDC     0     0     0
#39 2017 WashingtonDC     0     0     0
#40 2018 WashingtonDC     0     0     0
```

Comment: What libraries?

Comment: @BrianO'Donnell Aah yes, I forgot to include those. This is `tidyverse` solution, so `library(tidyverse)`

Comment: I gave you an up vote as it helped me solve some tougher problems but it is overly complex for this problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this with the `dplyr` package, making columns compatible classes and also do not set strings as factors:

```
library(dplyr)

cities <- c('Boston', 'Chicago', 'Denver', 'HOuston', 'LosAngeles', 'Miami', 'NewYork', 'WashingtonDC')
years <- as.numeric(2014:2018)
df <- expand.grid(Year=years, City=cities, TestA=0, TestB=0, TestC=0,  stringsAsFactors = F)
df[with(df, order(Year, City)),]

dfUpdate <- data.frame(Year=c(2016, 2015), City=c('Boston', 'Chicago'), 
                   TestA=c(12.23, 16.01), TestB=c('Joe', 'Sally'), TestC=c(1000, 1500), stringsAsFactors = F )

# Check which columns are not compatible you will see that there is an issue with TestB
# class(df$City) == class(dfUpdate$City)
# class(df$Year) == class(dfUpdate$Year)
# class(df$TestA) == class(dfUpdate$TestA)
# class(df$TestB) == class(dfUpdate$TestB)
# class(df$TestC) == class(dfUpdate$TestC)

# Correct incomptible class
df$TestB = as.character(df$TestB)

library(dplyr)
result = anti_join(df, dfUpdate, by=c("Year","City"))

result = merge(result, dfUpdate, all = T)
result = result[order(result$City),]
> result
   Year         City TestA TestB TestC
1  2014       Boston  0.00     0     0
9  2015       Boston  0.00     0     0
17 2016       Boston 12.23   Joe  1000
25 2017       Boston  0.00     0     0
33 2018       Boston  0.00     0     0
2  2014      Chicago  0.00     0     0
10 2015      Chicago 16.01 Sally  1500
18 2016      Chicago  0.00     0     0
26 2017      Chicago  0.00     0     0
34 2018      Chicago  0.00     0     0
3  2014       Denver  0.00     0     0
11 2015       Denver  0.00     0     0
19 2016       Denver  0.00     0     0
27 2017       Denver  0.00     0     0
35 2018       Denver  0.00     0     0
4  2014      HOuston  0.00     0     0
12 2015      HOuston  0.00     0     0
20 2016      HOuston  0.00     0     0
28 2017      HOuston  0.00     0     0
36 2018      HOuston  0.00     0     0
5  2014   LosAngeles  0.00     0     0
13 2015   LosAngeles  0.00     0     0
21 2016   LosAngeles  0.00     0     0
29 2017   LosAngeles  0.00     0     0
37 2018   LosAngeles  0.00     0     0
6  2014        Miami  0.00     0     0
14 2015        Miami  0.00     0     0
22 2016        Miami  0.00     0     0
30 2017        Miami  0.00     0     0
38 2018        Miami  0.00     0     0
7  2014      NewYork  0.00     0     0
15 2015      NewYork  0.00     0     0
23 2016      NewYork  0.00     0     0
31 2017      NewYork  0.00     0     0
39 2018      NewYork  0.00     0     0
8  2014 WashingtonDC  0.00     0     0
16 2015 WashingtonDC  0.00     0     0
24 2016 WashingtonDC  0.00     0     0
32 2017 WashingtonDC  0.00     0     0
40 2018 WashingtonDC  0.00     0     0
```

Comment: This is incorrect. You are simply joining both data sets. The new data for Chicago in 2015 should replace the original data for Chicago in 2015 and similarly for the data for Boston in 2016.

Comment: @BrianO'Donnell, thank you for noticing and for informing me. I have modified my answer and it should now provide the correct outcome.